# How to work with FormData in React and Next?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, multipartform-data

New to React and I'm building a dashboard page, and thought it will be having so many forms so I created a component for Input with label and I use that component to populate  element with my required format of input. On submit, I used FormData() to attempt to create or extract data from form without any tedious state management(which I don't feel to have in this situation).
But FormData() doesn't seem to work as expected, let me know where am I doing wrong.

Form component:

```js
import Input from "../micro components/Input"

export default function Form() {
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const fd = new FormData(e.target)
        console.log(fd)
        const res = await fetch('/api/admin/add', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: fd
        }).then(res => res.json())
        console.log(res)
    }

    return <>
        <div className="text-xl font-semibold select-none">Add a Hospital/Clinic</div>
        <form className="flex flex-col gap-3 mt-5" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label>Fields with <strong>*</strong> are mandatory</label>
            <Input name="Name" placeholder="hospital/clinic name" required />
            <Input name="Branch" placeholder="Locality Eg: Uppal; Madhapur etc" />
            {/* Regex pattern / ^[6-9]\d{9}$ /gi will match phone numbers of 10 digits starting with 6 7 8 9 */}
            <Input name="Phone - 10 digits" type="tel" placeholder="9876543210" pattern="^[6-9]\d{9}$" required />
            <Input name="Mail" type="email" placeholder="admin@hospital.com" required />
            <Input name="Full Address" placeholder="Recommended to paste from google maps" />
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </>
}
```

Input component:

```js
export default function Input({ name, type, placeholder, pattern, input, required }) {
    return (
        <label className="input-group input-group-vertical">
            <span className="select-none">{required ? '*' + name : name}</span>
            <input type={type} className="input input-bordered" pattern={pattern}
                placeholder={placeholder} value={input} required={required} />
        </label>
    )
}
```

server-side:

```js
export default async function AddHosp(req, res){
    console.log(req.body)
    return res.status(200).json({
        msg: 'testin'
    })
}
```

When I console.log request body on server-side, I get the following as output :
`------WebKitFormBoundaryPvEYMB5QuQqszbrx--`

I also tried accessing FormData elements at client-side but no success

PS: FormData isn't properly documented with examples afaik, if I'm wrong correct me

Comment: Duplicate question is entirely different and is not helping me in any way.... it used formRef ,  I didn't. I use custom `Input` component it doesn't and many more differences and question title might match in some way maybe

Comment: I didn't mark it as a duplicate but in essence it is because what you want to do is read a form as FormData and your components should render down to an HTML standard form (if not, adjust them) and then you can use the example on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects to read the form in as FormData. The deduplication efforts on StackOverflow can make asking questions tricky so don't be discouraged!